# ScrollView Not Visible swiftui

Tags: uiscrollview, swiftui

Projects github https://github.com/m3rtkoksal/Erupt

In my scrollviews only the first item is visible. When I scroll I can not see other items on the page. How can I see other scroll items? I have three Elements on Service struct but I can only see one of them. Other elements are just not visible even though I scroll. I should see tree scroll elements in the app but I only see one.

[image]

[image]

```
struct ScrollViewTwo: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            
            ForEach(Service.listDataSecond) { item in
                    CardViewTwo(item: item)
                }
            
            .frame(height: 150)
        }
      }
    }


struct ScrollViewSecondElement: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var price: String
    var image: String
    var title: String
    var explanation: String
}

struct Service {
    
    static let listDataSecond: [ScrollViewSecondElement] = [
        ScrollViewSecondElement(price: "$600", image: "iphone", title: "Iphone X", explanation: "64GB"),
        ScrollViewSecondElement(price: "$500", image: "xbox", title: "X Box", explanation: "500GB"),
        ScrollViewSecondElement(price: "$2000", image: "macmini", title: "Mac Mini", explanation: "512GB SSD")
    ]
}


struct CardViewTwo: View {
    var item: ScrollViewSecondElement
    var width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .frame(width: width - 100 , height: 120, alignment: .center)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            HStack {
                Image(item.image)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .leading)
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(item.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.body)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    Spacer()
                    Text(item.explanation)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.caption2)
                        .fontWeight(.light)
                    Spacer()
                    Text(item.price)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                }
                .frame( height: 110, alignment: .leading)
                .padding()
                VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    }
                    .frame(width: 5, height: 10)
                    .padding()
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Delete button tapped!")
                    }) {
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                            Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: 110, alignment: .trailing)
                .padding()
                .offset(y: -10)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a `Stack` inside the `scrollView`:

```
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack {
            ForEach(Service.listDataSecond) { item in
                CardViewTwo(item: item)
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 150)
    }
```

Also, consider using `Lazy(H\V)Stack` if you are targetting iOS 14 or later.

---

#### The code issue

Although the cause is described above, your specific code has another problem and that is in line `71` in the `contentView`, you are clipping the content as `.clipShape(Corners())`. This will hide extra space of the stack inside the scroll view. Get rid of that and see what happen.

Comment: It did not work. It scrolls but view is empty. I added to the question that image.

Comment: Can you provide a minimum reproducable project?

Comment: Maybe because I have two scrollviews. That is the reason why?

Comment: I've added github link Mojtaba Hosseini

Comment: line `71` in `contentView`. I described in the answer.

Comment: How can I cornerradius then?

Comment: Apply it to the proper view. I think the card itself is the one but you should find it with your desire.

Answer (score 0):

The `ForEach` by default form a group, so for horizontal scroll you need to wrap all dynamic content into `HStack`, as below

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14 (no changes in provided layout)

[image: demo]

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack {               // << here !!
            ForEach(Service.listDataSecond) { item in
                CardViewTwo(item: item)
            }
            .frame(height: 150)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mine is not like that.

Comment: When I scroll I can only see half of the scroll indicator line below my scrollviewTwo view.